# Gathering active visitors; assign each visitor an unique user row in database

Tags: php, javascript, database, database-design

I'm currently looking for the BEST and SMOOTHEST way to get the **active users** on my website using a particular page. (*purpose: think game lobby*).

I was thinking about storing each visitor in a table, with their **IP-adress** as primary key in the database, together with a **`lastAction`** field - which stores a timestamp of their last action.
Gathering the active users would then simply just be to gather all rows where the last action was within the correct amount of time.

The problem: people on the **same network** (same IP) would be identified as the **same user** - it'd be hard to tell if they actually were a real person or just a page refresh with an old session. You get the idea.

I'm looking for smoother ways to **separate users**, or preferably, get away from the whole IP-adress part. Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a session based algorithm to determine the count of 'active users'? If you setup your session handler to write to a database (instead of flatfile), you can run queries against rows within the table to determine how many visitors and which page they are currently viewing.

You can read about how to switch your session handler [here](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/session-handler.html), but it does appear to be outdated. I suspect more googling will result in newer implementations.